# Can I call fields from fact table on MDX?

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Is it possible to call field from fact table on MDX? or should I declare it on schema?

I have `age` field on my fact table. I need it to separate my `measures` value into '18-20', '21-25', etc.
Maybe it would look like this.

```
|        |all region             |
|        |city 1     |city2      |
|        |18-20|21-25|18-20|21-25|
```

Comment: Please add some examples of what you are trying to achieve in your question. I cannot understand what you are asking for as it is now.

Comment: Hi @Luc, have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to group by age, then your age is not used as a fact, but as an attribute. Hence, the age should be as an attribute column in a dimension. And the simplest way to implement the age groups would be to add another attribute column to that dimension table containing these groups.

Thus, technically, there should be an age column and an age group column in one of your dimension tables, probably a dimension table containing other data about people. That table should then be referenced by the fact table. As you did not describe the structure of your data warehouse tables, I am sorry cannot be more specific.

And: this does not mean that you cannot use the age as a measure in other contexts, as - since you write that the age is contained in your fact table, I am assuming you already use it as a measure.

Comment: Hi @FrankPl, sorry I don't get it. My English is poor. If you wish, can you explain it more detail? Thanks.